# Erro Estranho No Android

Tags: android

Bom estava com um projeto praticamente terminado em Android com o cliente testando e já dando OK para só mudar algumas imagens e texto do programa nada de mais, aí fui pegar esses dias novamente para testar o programa sem alterar nada ainda e não funciona mais sem eu fazer simplesmente nada, nem o programa que estava no meu celular funcionando também não funciona mais.

O erro é o seguinte abaixo:

> 11-05 16:06:31.691 3926-4274/br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Process:
>   br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina, PID: 3926
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that
>   has not called Looper.prepare() at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200) at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114) at
>   android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:327) at
>   android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:92) at
>   android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241) at
>   br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.view.MainActivity$FindByCpfClienteAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:151)
>   at
>   br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.view.MainActivity$FindByCpfClienteAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:108)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Minha classe abaixo aonde está dando erro:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText editTextCPF;
    private Button buttonConsultar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Carrega Os Campos Da Tela
        editTextCPF = findViewById(R.id.editTextCPF);
        buttonConsultar = findViewById(R.id.buttonConsultar);

        buttonConsultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                if (editTextCPF.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    String message = "Informe O CPF Para Entrar No Sistema.";

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (editTextCPF.getText().length() > 11) {
                    String message = "O CPF É Maior Que 11 Dígitos.";

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (editTextCPF.getText().length() < 11) {
                    String message = "O CPF É Menor Que 11 Dígitos.";

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                    toast.show();
                } else if (editTextCPF.getText().toString().isEmpty() == false) {

                    try {

                        FindByCpfClienteAsyncTask findByCpfClienteModelAsyncTask = new FindByCpfClienteAsyncTask();
                        findByCpfClienteModelAsyncTask.execute("https://escoficinawebservice.herokuapp.com/cliente/" + editTextCPF.getText());

                        ClienteSaidaDTO clienteSaidaDTO = findByCpfClienteModelAsyncTask.get();

                        if (clienteSaidaDTO.getCode().equals(1)) {
                            String message = "CPF Encontrado.";

                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                            toast.show();

                            message = "Buscando As Informações Do Cliente.";

                            toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                            toast.show();

                            Intent intentESCOficinaActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ESCOficinaActivity.class);
                            intentESCOficinaActivity.putExtra("clienteSaidaDTO", new Gson().toJson(clienteSaidaDTO));
                            startActivity(intentESCOficinaActivity);

                        } else {
                            String message = "CPF Não Encontrado.";

                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String message = "Erro: " + e.getMessage();

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    class FindByCpfClienteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ClienteSaidaDTO> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Context context = getApplicationContext();

            String message = "Aguarde... Verificando CPF.";
            int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
            toast.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ClienteSaidaDTO doInBackground(String... params) {
            String urlString = params[0];

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(urlString);

            ClienteSaidaDTO clienteSaidaDTO = null;

            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();

                if (httpEntity != null) {
                    InputStream inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

                    String json = toString(inputStream);
                    inputStream.close();

                    clienteSaidaDTO = getCliente(json);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                String message = "Erro: " + e.getMessage();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                toast.show();

                return null;
            }

            return clienteSaidaDTO;
        }

        private ClienteSaidaDTO getCliente(String jsonString) {

            ClienteSaidaDTO clienteSaidaDTO = new ClienteSaidaDTO();

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObjectConvertString = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONObject jsonObjectEntity = jsonObjectConvertString.getJSONObject("entity");
                JSONObject jsonObjectClienteModel = jsonObjectEntity.getJSONObject("clienteModel");

                ClienteModel clienteModel = new ClienteModel();

                clienteSaidaDTO.setCode(jsonObjectEntity.getInt("code"));
                clienteSaidaDTO.setMessage(jsonObjectEntity.getString("message"));

                clienteModel.setCodigoCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getInt("codigoCliente"));
                clienteModel.setNomeCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("nomeCliente"));
                clienteModel.setCpfCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("cpfCliente"));
                clienteModel.setRgCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("rgCliente"));
                clienteModel.setEmailCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("emailCliente"));

                Long dataCadastrocliente = jsonObjectClienteModel.getLong("dataCadastroCliente");
                clienteModel.setDataCadastroCliente(new Date(dataCadastrocliente));

                Long dataNascimentoCliente = jsonObjectClienteModel.getLong("dataNascimentoCliente");
                clienteModel.setDataNascimentoCliente(new Date(dataNascimentoCliente));

                if (jsonString.contains("dddCelular1Cliente")) {
                    clienteModel.setDddCelular1Cliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getInt("dddCelular1Cliente"));
                }

                if (jsonString.contains("numeroCelular1Cliente")) {
                    clienteModel.setNumeroCelular1Cliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("numeroCelular1Cliente"));
                }

                if (jsonString.contains("dddCelular2Cliente")) {
                    clienteModel.setDddCelular2Cliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getInt("dddCelular2Cliente"));
                }

                if (jsonString.contains("numeroCelular2Cliente")) {
                    clienteModel.setNumeroCelular2Cliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("numeroCelular2Cliente"));
                }

                if (jsonString.contains("dddTelefoneCliente")) {
                    clienteModel.setDddTelefoneCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getInt("dddTelefoneCliente"));
                }

                if (jsonString.contains("numeroTelefoneCliente")) {
                    clienteModel.setNumeroTelefoneCliente(jsonObjectClienteModel.getString("numeroTelefoneCliente"));
                }

                clienteSaidaDTO.setClienteModel(clienteModel);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                String message = "Erro: " + e.getMessage();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
                toast.show();

                return null;
            }

            return clienteSaidaDTO;
        }

        private String toString(InputStream is) throws IOException {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int lidos;
            while ((lidos = is.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                baos.write(bytes, 0, lidos);
            }
            return new String(baos.toByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Não posso afirmar com certeza, mas acho que o codigo está sendo executado de forma errada. Um exemplo é a chamada do Toast. No doInBackground, você NÃO, em HIPÓTESE NENHUMA, deve fazer chamadas de UI, e você está atualizando a UI também antes de ter um resultado efetivo do doInBackground, pois n tem o onPostExecute implementado. Acho melhor dar uma revisada nas chamadas e métodos da AsyncTask. Pode ser isso o erro (e também estranho que antes funcionava). Lembrando também que a implementação muda de Android para Android (versão do Android)

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:200) at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:114) at android.widget.Toast$TN.(Toast.java:327) at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:92) at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:241) at br.com.escconsultoria.escoficina.view.MainActivity$FindByCpfClienteAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:151)

Basicamente você está tentando criar um Toast a partir de uma thread que não é a main, neste bloco:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    int time = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    String message = "Erro: " + e.getMessage();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, time);
    toast.show();
}
```

Da [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> doInBackground(Params...), invoked on the background thread immediately after onPreExecute() finishes executing. This step is used to perform background computation that can take a long time.

---

Tudo que é executado no `doInBackground` acontece em uma thread no background. Provavelmente este erro nunca aconteceu porque o fluxo de execução nunca caiu no bloco `catch`.

Para corrigir o problema você deverá alterar sua lógica para criar o Toast na main thread. Uma possibilidade é utilizar o método `onPostExecute` da própria `AsyncTask`.